# submitAutocompleteForm not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following Pluralsights Building Applications with ASP.Net MVC4 video. I've created a form that shows the autocomplete, which is working, but now I'm trying to submit the form when a selection is made from the autocomplete list. As far as I can tell my code is identical to the tutorial. What am I missing?

**Javscript: otf.js**

```
    $(function () {
        var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
            var $form = $(this);

            var options = {
                url: $form.attr("action"),
                type: $form.attr("method"),
                data: $form.serialize()
            };


            $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
                var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
                $target.replaceWith(data);
            });
            return false;
        };

        var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.val(ui.item.label);

            var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
            $form.submit();
        }


        var createAutocomplete = function () {
            var $input = $(this);
            var options = {
                source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
                select: submitAutocompleteForm
            };

            $input.autocomplete(options);
        };


        $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
        $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
    });
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")"
      data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#restaurantList">

    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete")" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
</form>


@Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
```

**_Restaurants.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

<div id="restaurantList">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City @item.Country</div>
            <div>Reviews: @item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Home Controller**

```
using OdeToFood.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OdeToFood.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

        public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
        {
            var model =
                _db.Restaurants
                .Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(term))
                .Take(10)
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    label = r.Name
                });
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null) //string searchTerm = null adds filtering
        {   var model =
                _db.Restaurants
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Reviews.Average(review => review.Rating))
                .Where(r => searchTerm == null || r.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm)) //adds filtering
                .Take(10) //Only difference as above
                .Select(r => new RestaurantListViewModel
                            {
                                Id = r.Id,
                                Name = r.Name,
                                City = r.City,
                                Country = r.Country,
                                CountOfReviews = r.Reviews.Count()
                            });
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {//asynchinization
                return PartialView("_Restaurants", model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include three jquery files:

```
 jquery-ui.css         // css file
 jquery-{version}.js   // version you are using
 jquery-ui.js
```

In the View, the input tag would be:

```
<input type="text" name="term" data-video-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete")" />
```

And the JavaScript would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// event that should be called on autocomplete
var createAutoComplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);

    var options = {
        source: $input.attr('data-video-autocomplete') 
    };

    $input.autocomplete(options);        
}

// wire up the autocomplete to the input box
$('input[data-video-autocomplete]').each(createAutoComplete);    

})
```

And finally, in the Controller, the handler:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
    var list = db.Videos.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(term)).Take(10).Select(r => new { label = r.Name });

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.val(ui.item.label);
        $input.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some insight as to why that piece of code should be changed?